# Unable to list contents of bucket

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I try to run the [example of listing the contents of a bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html), I get the following error.  I've tried running this on my local machine as opening a file in the browser and then also on a remote server.  Origin 'null' happens when I run on local machine.  Both cases fail in the same way:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load `my-bucket.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com`. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

This is likely a permissions issue as I begin to learn about policies and CORS, and the IAM service in general.  I seem to have successfully hard-coded my credentials OK, as `AWS.config.getCredentials` successfully completes.

```
var AWS_BUCKET_NAME = 'my-bucket';
var AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'myId';
var AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'myKey';
var AWS_REGION = 'us-west-1';
var AWS_API_VERSION = '2012-10-17';

var listBucketContents = function() {
  var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: AWS_BUCKET_NAME}});
  bucket.listObjects(function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Could not load objects from S3');
    } else {
      console.log('Loaded ' + data.Contents.length + ' items from S3');
      for (var i = 0; i < data.Contents.length; i++) {
        console.log(data.Contents[i].Key);
      }
    }
  });
};

var initializeWindow = function() {
  AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: AWS_REGION,
    apiVersion: AWS_API_VERSION
  });

  AWS.config.getCredentials(function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err.stack); // credentials not loaded
    else console.log("Access Key:", AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId);
  });

  listBucketContents();
};
```

My user permissions on the AWS console:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets"],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

And my CORS permissions on that bucket in the AWS Console are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>x-amz-meta-custom-header</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed the wrong region.  When logged into the AWS Console, you can check the properties on your bucket.  US Standard is `us-east-1`.

`var AWS_REGION = us-east-1;`

You can also check the endpoint under the Static Website Hosting section: `my-bucket-name.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`